# A query which shows changes of a column from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

i have table which include my product table's logs like that:

```
process_time             product_id  product_type_id
04.07.2009 14:08:43      5           4
05.07.2009 15:08:43      5           4
06.07.2009 16:08:43      5           6
07.07.2009 16:08:43      5           6
08.07.2009 17:08:43      5           4
08.07.2009 18:08:43      5           4
```

I want to write a query which shows the changes of product_type_id. For the example above, the result of my query should be like that:

```
process_time             product_id  product_type_id
04.07.2009 14:08:43      5           4
06.07.2009 16:08:43      5           6
08.07.2009 17:08:43      5           4
```

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
select * from
(select process_time, product_id, product_type_id
,lag(product_type_id) over (partition by product_id order by process_time) as prevrow
,lead(product_type_id) over (partition by product_id order by process_time) as nextrow
from products )
where nextrow <> product_type_id or nextrow is null;
```

For all who like to see how this works:

```
create table products (process_time  timestamp, product_id number, product_type_id number);

insert into products values (to_date('2009-07-04 14:08:43','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),5,4);
insert into products values (to_date('2009-07-05 15:08:43','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),5,4);
insert into products values (to_date('2009-07-06 16:08:43','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),5,6);
insert into products values (to_date('2009-07-07 16:08:43','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),5,6);
insert into products values (to_date('2009-07-08 17:08:43','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),5,4);
insert into products values (to_date('2009-07-08 18:08:43','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),5,4);

commit;

select process_time, product_id, product_type_id
,lag(product_type_id) over (partition by product_id order by process_time) as prevrow
,lead(product_type_id) over (partition by product_id order by process_time) as nextrow
from products 
order by process_time;

select * from
(select process_time, product_id, product_type_id
,lag(product_type_id) over (partition by product_id order by process_time) as prevrow
,lead(product_type_id) over (partition by product_id order by process_time) as nextrow
from products )
where nextrow <> product_type_id or nextrow is null;

commit;

drop table products;
```

Executed we get:

```
Table created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
Commit complete.

PROCESS_TIME                    PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_TYPE_ID    PREVROW    NEXTROW
------------------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
04-JUL-09 02.08.43.000000 PM             5               4                     4
05-JUL-09 03.08.43.000000 PM             5               4          4          6
06-JUL-09 04.08.43.000000 PM             5               6          4          6
07-JUL-09 04.08.43.000000 PM             5               6          6          4
08-JUL-09 05.08.43.000000 PM             5               4          6          4
08-JUL-09 06.08.43.000000 PM             5               4          4           


6 rows selected.

PROCESS_TIME                    PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_TYPE_ID    PREVROW    NEXTROW
------------------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
05-JUL-09 03.08.43.000000 PM             5               4          4          6
07-JUL-09 04.08.43.000000 PM             5               6          6          4
08-JUL-09 06.08.43.000000 PM             5               4          4           


3 rows selected.
Commit complete.
Table dropped.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`LAG` analytic function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm#i1327527) to find the prior value of the product_type_id column. If the current and prior values are different then that should be the row that you want. For the first row, the `LAG` function will return null because there is no prior row so you will also need to test for that.

```
select 
  process_time, 
  product_id, 
  product_type_id, 
from (
  select 
    process_time, 
    product_id, 
    product_type_id, 
    lag(product_type_id) over (order by process_time) as prior_product_type_id
  from the_table
)
where 
  (prior_product_type_id <> product_type_id or prior_product_type_id is null)
```